# AngularJs minification process

Tags: angularjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm finishing a web app and all works like a charm.

I use Grunt to join all my .js files in one unique file and that's the one I use in the index.html file to load the code.

The issue is when I use the .min. version of the file generated by grunt using 'grunt-contrib-uglify' task.

When I reload the page, the following error arises:

> angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A222)

I've been reading around this on Google but no success.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**:

This is a typical file controller (all have the same structure):

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("post", []);
  var controllers = {};
  controllers.postCtrl = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'myFactory', function($scope, $rootScope, myFactory) {
      $scope.loading  = {state:false};
      $scope.filters  = $scope.filters  || myFactory.authors;
      $scope.init = function() {
          var idx = myFactory.get_author_by_index(Number($('input[name="author"]').val()));
          $scope.filterSelected = $scope.filters[idx];
          angular.element(document).ready(function () {
              angular.forEach($('div.general_page_content').find('a'), function(value, index) {
                  $(value).attr('target', "_new");
              })
              angular.forEach($('div.general_page_content').find('iframe'), function(value, index) {
                  $(value).attr("width", "100%");
              })
              angular.forEach($('div.general_page_content').find('img'), function(value, index) {
                  $(value).attr("width", "100%").css('width', '100%');
              })
              myFactory.containerResize();
          });
      }
      $rootScope.$on('loading', function(evt, value) {
          $scope.loading.state = value;
      });
      $rootScope.$on('autocomplete:focus', function(ev) {
          $scope.search_focus = true;
      });
      $rootScope.$on('autocomplete:blur', function(ev) {
          $scope.search_focus = false;
      });
      $scope.showSocialShare = function(ev) {
          $scope.url  = decodeURIComponent($('input[name="url"]').val());
          $scope.text = decodeURIComponent($('input[name="text"]').val());
          $scope.img  = decodeURIComponent($('input[name="img"]').val());
          myFactory.showSocialShare($scope, ev);
      };
      $scope.favorite_post = function(ev, id, title) {
          myFactory.favorite_post($scope, ev, id, title);
      }

      $scope.fetchPostsChange = function(selected) {
          document.location = '/blog/?author='+selected.id;
      }
      $scope.search = function(text) {
          document.location = '/blog/?search='+encodeURIComponent(text);
      }
      $scope.go_to_favorites_post = function() {
          document.location = '/blog/archive/';
      }
      $scope.init();
  }];
  app.controller(controllers);
})();
```

**UPDATE**:

I took only two .js files and process them to minified it and check if the same error arises or not. The curious thing is that taking into account only two files, the same error arises, so I paste the minified file for you to be able to detect what's wrong.

```
!function(){angular.module("myapp",["ngMaterial","ngMessages","ngStorage","toaster","ngMdIcons","lvl.services","smart-table","angularGrid","ngFileUpload","angular-timeline","header","dashboard","sidebar","autocomplete","timeline","sidebarCollection","myappFactory","objectCtrl","homeCtrl","Collections","Collection","posts","post","model","postArchive","720kb.socialshare","services","footer"]).config(function(a,b,c){a.theme("default").primaryPalette("lime").accentPalette("grey").warnPalette("red"),a.theme("darkTheme").primaryPalette("lime").accentPalette("grey").warnPalette("red").dark(),b.enabled(!1),c.get("user")})}(),function(){var a=angular.module("autocomplete",[]),b={},c={};b.autocompleteCtrl=["$http","$scope","$mdBottomSheet","$sessionStorage","myappFactory",function(a,b,c,d,e){b.init=function(){b.session=d,angular.isUndefined(b.session.advance_search)&&(b.session.advance_search={select_all:!0,show_cost:!0,show_free:!0,items:[{name:"Thingiverse",selected:!0},{name:"Youmagine",selected:!0},{name:"MyMinifactory",selected:!0},{name:"Cults 3D",selected:!0},{name:"Pinshape",selected:!0},{name:"Turbosquid",selected:!0},{name:"Shapeways",selected:!0},{name:"GrabCAD",selected:!0},{name:"CGTrader",selected:!0},{name:"Threeding",selected:!0}]})},b.querySearch=function(c){var d=c.trim();return d&&d.length>2?(b.isFetching=!0,a.get(e._myapp_link+"/api/index.php/myapp/autocomplete/"+encodeURIComponent(d)).then(function(a){return a.data})):void 0},b.collectionSearch=function(c){var d=c.trim();return d&&d.length>2?(b.isFetching=!0,a.get(e._myapp_link+"/api/index.php/myapp/collection_search/"+encodeURIComponent(d)).then(function(a){return a.data})):void 0},b.search=function(a){var c="";b.session.advance_search.show_cost&&!b.session.advance_search.show_free?c+=" free:0 ":!b.session.advance_search.show_cost&&b.session.advance_search.show_free&&(c+=" free:1 "),angular.forEach(b.session.advance_search.items,function(a,d){(b.session.advance_search.select_all||a.selected)&&(c+=" plataforma:"+a.name)}),window.location="/?search="+encodeURIComponent(a)+"&params="+Base64.encode(c)},b.go_to_collection=function(a){window.location="/collections/"+encodeURIComponent(a)},b.showAdvancedSearch=function(){c.show({templateUrl:"/advanced_search_sheet.html",controller:"ListBottomSheetCtrl"})},b.init()}],b.ListBottomSheetCtrl=["$scope","$mdBottomSheet","$sessionStorage","myappFactory",function(a,b,c,d){a.session=c,a.toggle_all_sites=function(){a.session.advance_search.select_all=!a.session.advance_search.select_all,a.session.advance_search.select_all&&angular.forEach(a.session.advance_search.items,function(a,b){a.selected=!0})},a.toggle_advance_search=function(b){if(a.session.advance_search.select_all)a.session.advance_search.items[b].selected=!0,d.showMessage({msg:"Uncheck 'All repositories' first!"});else if(a.session.advance_search.items[b].selected=!a.session.advance_search.items[b].selected,!a.session.advance_search.items[b].selected){var c=0;angular.forEach(a.session.advance_search.items,function(a,b){a.selected&&++c}),c||(a.session.advance_search.items[b].selected=!0,d.showMessage({msg:"There must be at least 1 respository selected!"}))}},a.free_cost_checked=function(b){var c="cost"==b?!a.session.advance_search.show_cost:!a.session.advance_search.show_free;c?"cost"==b?a.session.advance_search.show_cost=!0:a.session.advance_search.show_free=!0:"cost"==b?a.session.advance_search.show_free?a.session.advance_search.show_cost=!1:d.showMessage({msg:"Free and Price cannot be unchecked!"}):"free"==b&&(a.session.advance_search.show_cost?a.session.advance_search.show_free=!1:d.showMessage({msg:"Free and Price cannot be unchecked!"}))}}],c.myEnter=function(){return function(a,b,c){b.bind("keydown keypress",function(b){13===b.which&&(a.$apply(function(){a.search(a.searchText)}),b.preventDefault())})}},c.onBlur=["$rootScope","$mdUtil","$timeout",function(a,b,c){return{require:"^mdAutocomplete",link:function(d,e,f,g){c(function(){var c=(e.find("input"),e[0],g.blur),h=g.focus;g.blur=function(){c.call(g),b.nextTick(function(){a.$broadcast("autocomplete:blur"),d.$eval(f.mdBlur,{$mdAutocomplete:g})})},g.focus=function(){h.call(g),b.nextTick(function(){a.$broadcast("autocomplete:focus"),d.$eval(f.mdFocus,{$mdAutocomplete:g})})}})}}}],a.controller(b).directive(c)}();
```

Comment: Have you used minification-safe injection? Something like `blah.service("serviceName", ["$http", function($http) {} ]);`

Comment: you need to use ng-annotate or grunt-ng-annotate plugin

Comment: @HopefulLlama Yes I read that in blog and took into account in each controller.

Comment: could you edit your question to include a controller that you have written?

Comment: @YOU I have ng-annotate plugin in Grunt but do not know how to use it.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/v2.0.13/app/templates/Gruntfile.js#L334

Comment: @MohitYadav Updated!

Comment: You need to check the order of the minified file, you need to make sure your modules are being created before using them for example you need to make sure `angular.module('module', []);` is before `angular.module('module')`

Comment: The minification for code snippet appears fine, but as George Lee says, there's more going on here.

Comment: @GeorgeLee That makes sense. How can I vary the order in which the grunt task take files?

Comment: @domoindal that unfortunately I don't know as I don't use Grunt

Comment: @GeorgeLee I pasted the minified code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you certainly found on Google, that error depends on `Variable Mangling` https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#mangle.

So, when you mangle `$rootScope` becomes `a` and, of course, **angular dependency injection** cannot resolve it:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .run(function($injector) {
    console.log(
      "$rootScope exists?", 
      $injector.has('$rootScope')
    );
    
    try {
      // mangle $rootscope => a
      $injector.get('a');
    } catch(e) { 
      console.log('a exists?', e.message); 
    }
    
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<section ng-app="test"></section>
```

There are many ways to manage this issue:

1. Disable Variable Mangling (not a good way, but is a solution).
2. Always use [Angular DI Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

   a. Array notation: `someModule.run(["$rootScope", function(a) {}]);`

   b. $inject Property: `runFn.$inject = ['$rootScope']; function runFn(a) {}; someModule.run(runFn);`
3. Use [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/mgol/grunt-ng-annotate) that does annotation at build time. I suggest you this option because you don't need to take care about annotation...

> **Important thing**:
>   Always run your code in [`angular strict di`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) mode, that gives you the opportunity of control each annotation issue.

Comment: Hi, I used your method and worked but now I have little issue related to a $mdDialog controller. I arises a [$injector:strictdi] error and do not know how to declare it. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think could be possible an annotation issue on `Angular Material Modal`, you should have a look at their github, find if there are a issue... by the way, it is almost impossible in my opinion... Have you a resolve? (or something else). `ngAnnotate`, sometimes, needs manual annotation...

Comment: Yes, You have to manual annotate. I had to use controller_name.$inject to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you minify, each module's injections must be named. So before you may have had:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($route) {
});
```

Now you must name/declare them as well otherwise angular doens't know what to inject:

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['$route', function($route) {
}]);
```

**Why?**

Minification turns everything to small variables amongst other things. So our factory becomes:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function(a) {
      a.<functioncall>
});
```

Angular doens't know what "a" is and so must be told:

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['$route', function(a) {
      a.<functioncall>
}]);
```

And so it now knows and a= $route and so on.

Comment: You will need to show your code as this is the most common problem with minification. Track your error into the minifiied file and paste it here.

Comment: @domoindal If you expand the minified file in Chrome using the {} button in the source, which line does is break on (copy the line). thanks.

Comment: The minified .js is 150Kb. Also, other user indicates me that my problem may come from the order in which are placed

Comment: That's going to be tricky to debug, I take it Chrome just chokes pressing the expand source button?

Comment: Hi again. Testing somethings, I decided to only take two files and minified it. First, it is shorter than taking into account all .js files and for a better checking. I get the same error. How can I send you the result file?

Comment: Usual way, place it in a jsbin, public dropbox or other on line tool.